# wxPython wx.TextCtrl dynamically resizing to fill panel width

Tags: wxpython, width, textctrl

I want a `wx.TextCtrl` to take the entire remaining width of a panel. It is placed with a `wx.StaticText` and a `wx.Button` in a horizontal `wx.BoxSizer` in a vertical `wx.BoxSizer` in a `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel` (which is `self` below):

```
# create TextCtrl
self.fileNameInput = wx.TextCtrl (self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
# create horizontal sizer with 3 items
self.fileNameSizer = wx.BoxSizer (wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.fileNameSizer.Add (wx.StaticText (self, -1, 'none'), flag=(wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL))
self.fileNameSizer.Add (self.fileNameInput, proportion=1, flag=(wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL))
self.fileNameSizer.Add (wx.Button (self, label='Button'), flag=(wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL))
# create vertical sizer
self.SetSizer (wx.BoxSizer (wx.VERTICAL))
self.GetSizer ().Add (self.fileNameSizer)
```

Neither `proportion` nor `wx.EXPAND` help to make the `TextCtrl` larger, presumably because the sizer looks at the `TextCtrl`s own width. But I did not find any style or flag for the `'TextCtrl' to make it variable-width..?

Thanks for ideas!

EDIT: 
Replaced "..." by something working

Comment: You'll get more answers if you make it easier for people.  This would be much easier to answer if you posted a self-contained minimal example that would actually run.  I think I know what's wrong, but I don't want to post an answer until I check it, and I'm not going to spend all time replacing "..."s, etc.

Comment: @tom10: thanks for being so thorough, but I wanted to keep uninteresting stuff outside and assumed I would be able to figure out the details if I get a hint from someone who thinks he knows what's wrong... :-| Anyway, I replaced the ...s

Comment: It would be very helpful if you create self-contained minimal runnable example which demonstrates the problem. Similar to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that what is wrong is this line:

```
self.GetSizer().Add(self.fileNameSizer)
```

There should be some of `proportion=1` and/or `flag=wx.EXPAND` to make the nested sizer match its master size.

Something like this:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Label")
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Test")

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="ABOVE")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="BELLOW")

        self.horizontal = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.horizontal.Add(self.label, flag=wx.CENTER)
        self.horizontal.Add(self.text, proportion=1, flag=wx.CENTER)
        self.horizontal.Add(self.button, flag=wx.CENTER)

        self.vertical = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vertical.Add(self.button1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.vertical.Add(self.horizontal, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.vertical.Add(self.button2, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.vertical)  
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

BTW: Please stop adding space before `(` in method calls. Also I would recommend object oriented approach so you do not loose access to your GUI objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was looking at the wrong sizer... silly me. And yes, I do already follow your OO advice, but why should I keep function and `(` together (apart from style, I mean)?

Comment: Just for the style. It is a common convention. There are a few styles used, but this is so weird that it becomes hard to read.

Comment: Well, I'll try. :-)  Thanks for the background!