# Is there a way to allow the user to re size a text control in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

The question is pretty much in the title, not much to add here.  I'm trying to allow the user to dynamically size multi-line text controls just as they can re-size the panel (I set the default, but they are free to change it).  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text control will expand along with the panel if it is added to a sizer with the wx.EXPAND flag and the proportion is set to be greater than 0 (see [wxPython wx.TextCtrl dynamically resizing to fill panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407382/wxpython-wx-textctrl-dynamically-resizing-to-fill-panel-width)). There is no way to add a handle to the native widgets that will let the user resize just the widget itself.

You would need to create some kind of custom widget to do that. There is information about creating custom widgets on the wxPython wiki or you could look at the source of the widgets in wx.lib

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at wx.lib.resizewidget and the ResizeWidget sample in the demo.

Comment: This should be a comment, but I'll look into it